# How do I test that the method has been called in jasmine?

Tags: javascript, testing, bdd, jasmine

I'm a bit confused with spying on jasmine. I have a code like this, but I'm not sure how to test it.

```
var params = {
    param1: "",
    param2: "link",
    param3: "1", 
    param4 : "1"
};
var func = new myFunction(params );
func.doSomething();
```

How do test that func.doSomething has been called.

This is the test I have written so far

```
describe("Library", function() {

  beforeEach(function() {
  });

  it("should include correct parameters", function() {
      expect(params.param1).toEqual("");
      expect(params.param2).toEqual("link");
      expect(params.param3).toEqual("1");
      expect(params.param4).toEqual("1");
  });

  it("should show that method doSomething is called with zero arguments", function() {
          // I'm not sure how to write test for this.
  });
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you want to use `toHaveBeenCalledWith()`:

```
it("should show that method doSomething is called with zero arguments", function() {
    // Ensure the spy was called with the correct number of arguments
    // In this case, no arguments
    expect(func.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is what I have done.   
spyOn(func, "doSomething");
func.doSomething();
expect(func.doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();

But I have a silly question, wouldn't it mean that func.doSomething() is called inside the test and not test the behaviour of the real code? I'm pretty new at this so forgive me for asking silly question.

Comment: And if you want to specifiy how many times :
expect(component.func).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);

Answer (score 3):

If spy function has been called exactly once, use `toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith` matcher:

```
expect(mySpy).toHaveBeenCalledOnceWith('', 'link', "1", "1");
```

---

It combines `toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)` and `toHaveBeenCalledWith()` matchers.

Coming with `Jasmine 3.6`.